# Fixar barra de tabs abaixo de barra de navegação (navs x navbar)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

#### Objetivo

Criar uma barra de menu em tabs, abaixo de uma barra de menu, ambas fixas.

---

#### Cenário teste

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Bootstrap
  </a>
</nav>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs sticky-top">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<br>
<p>1</p>
<br>
<p>2</p>
<br>
<p>3</p>
<br>
<p>4</p>
<br>
<p>5</p>
<br>
<p>6</p>
<br>
<p>7</p>
<br>
<p>8</p>
<br>
<p>9</p>

</div>
```

---

#### Problema

Quando uso `fixed-top` na barra superior, o conteúdo fica já abaixo da mesma.
Se uso `sticky-top`, fica correto.

Já na fixação do menu de tabs, se uso `sticky-top`, ela não fixa, e fica sobe em cima da barra superior, e se uso `fixed-top`, ela fica escondida atrás da barra superior.

---

#### Dúvida

- Existe solução padrão no BS4 para resolver esse problema?
- Caso não, quais seriam as opções?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é só colocar os dois elementos dentro de uma mesma `<div>` e adicionar a classe `.sticky-top` nela?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Bootstrap
      </a>
    </nav>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <br>
  <p>1</p>
  <br>
  <p>2</p>
  <br>
  <p>3</p>
  <br>
  <p>4</p>
  <br>
  <p>5</p>
  <br>
  <p>6</p>
  <br>
  <p>7</p>
  <br>
  <p>8</p>
  <br>
  <p>9</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para o `position:sticky` ele precisa de um top: definido, mesmo que seja `0`. Então no seu caso o top tem que ser a altura da `nav`, `56px`... Ai vc cria uma classe com a altura da `nav` e coloca na `aba` como fiz abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que na classe default do Bootstrap já tem um `top` de `0`. Então vc tem que ajustar isso com uma classe

Veja como fica com o ajuste

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
.abas {
  top: 56px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Bootstrap
      </a>
    </nav>
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs sticky-top abas">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <br>
    <p>1</p>
    <br>
    <p>2</p>
    <br>
    <p>3</p>
    <br>
    <p>4</p>
    <br>
    <p>5</p>
    <br>
    <p>6</p>
    <br>
    <p>7</p>
    <br>
    <p>8</p>
    <br>
    <p>9</p>
    
    </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```